# toState.url value is not an absolute hash for nested states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get `url` of `toState` object in `$stateChangeStart` event for a state `basic.tasks`:

```
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                ...
                   console.log(toState.name);  // > basic.tasks
                   console.log(toState.url);   // > /tasks
                ...
            }
```

State Config:

```
 $stateProviderRef
 .state('basic',{
         url: '/b',
         template: require('source/basic/templates/basic.html'),
         controller: 'BasicController',
         abstract: true
         })
 .state('basic.tasks', {
         url: '/tasks',
         template: require('source/basic/templates/tasks/tasks.html'),
         controller: 'TasksController',
       })
```

The value of toState.url is `/tasks` instead of `/b/tasks`. Is there any way to get full hash including parent states.

I tried with `$window.location.hash`, but its giving only full hash path of `fromState` since it doesn't update until state change completes.

Comment: Can you add quotes to `BasicController` and try again ? May be the first state is not correctly interpreted by the JS

Comment: Sorry, it's not the problem. I just missed the quotes for controller name in this question only. I will edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no simple way to do this unless you just add the parent state to the url, but if you're looking for a more dynamic way then this could be one option. I'm not sure if you have the hashtag in your url (usually it is there and in this we use it just for the regexp to remove the hashtag - but it looks something like this http://localhost:8100/#/app in localhost) but if you do, you could try something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  var href = $state.href(toState.name);
  var regexp = new RegExp('#','g');
  href = href.replace(regexp, '');
  console.log(href);
});
```

If you have parameters in your url for some state you can add them to the absolute url with `toParams` since the parameters do not get added to the url with this function on `stateChangeStart`. It would work directly on `stateChangeSuccess`.

**EDIT:**

As Ganesh Matkam said in the comment section there actually is an easy solution for including stateParams to the url. It's as simple as:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  var href = $state.href(toState.name, toParams);
  var regexp = new RegExp('#','g');
  href = href.replace(regexp, '');
  console.log(href);
});
```

Comment: Wow, `$state.href` is the solution for my problem. I searched for `$state.href` for more details and found that parameters can also be added to the url by passing params object to `$state.href` function as second argument like this: `var href = $state.href(toState.name, toParams)`. So please edit your answer so that I will accept it as perfect solution. Thank you _thepio_.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't/haven't researched it that much but your addition seems to work perfectly. Nice catch! I edited my answer to include your addition to it.